# Upload Video to Youtube via REST Api Using Swift 3 & AlamoFire

Tags: ios, swift, rest, youtube

I am new to iOS development & learning Swift 3 currently. However I'm stuck in a task to upload video to my youtube channel via YouTube DATA API insert.

As per Google instruction, we need to first get Access Token from Auth 2.0 by declaring the scope first

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload

I'm unable to get the Access Token using my Client ID which I have created on Google Developers Console. Also I don't find any Swift library available on Google which could have helped me easily.

Here is my tried sample code

```
func uploadVideo(accessToken) {


        Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos", method: .post, parameters: ["part":"snippet", "autoLevels":true], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, "access_token": "\(accessToken)").responseJSON { (response) in

        if let json = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
        }

    }
```

I will be really thankful to you

Comment: Your sample code is for uploading a video. Is your question about getting an access token?

Comment: Yes and also please verify I'm choosing the right way to send my video request to youtube server